# Input from command line using atoi function

Tags: c, memory-alignment, atoi

I have written a small program to check the page alignment.
This program works fine when I hardcode the value of address variable in program itself, but when I try to take them from commandline using argc and argv values, the output goes haphazard, does the value of uint64_t cannot be recovered from commandline using atoi function..?

normal code, one can see the value of address being hardcoded into program itself.

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include<stdlib.h>
  3
  4 int aligned(uint64_t addr, uint64_t pgsize){
  5     return ((uint64_t)addr % pgsize == 0);
  6 }
  7
  8 int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  9     uint32_t i;
 10     uint64_t addr, size;
 11     addr=0x1900000000;
 12     size=0x100000000 ;
 13
 14     for(i=0;i<7;i++)
 15         if(aligned(addr,size>>i)){
 16                 printf("Aligned to %#lx\n",size>>i);
 17         }
 18         else
 19             printf("Not Aligned to %#lx\n",size>>i);
 20     return 0;
 21 }
```

output

```
[souravhimanshu] ./aligned
Aligned to 0
Aligned to 0x80000000
Aligned to 0x40000000
Aligned to 0x20000000
Aligned to 0x10000000
Aligned to 0x8000000
Aligned to 0x4000000
```

code with command line input

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include<stdlib.h>
  3
  4 int aligned(uint64_t addr, uint64_t pgsize){
  5     return ((uint64_t)addr % pgsize == 0);
  6 }
  7
  8 int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  9     uint32_t i;
 10     uint64_t addr, size;
 11     if(argc<2){
 12         printf("usage ./chkalign <address>\n");
 13         exit(-1);
 14     }
 15     addr=atoi(argv[1]);
 16     printf("%#lx",addr);
 17     //addr=0x1900000000;
 18     size=0x100000000 ;
 19
 20     for(i=0;i<7;i++)
 21         if(aligned(addr,size>>i)){
 22                 printf("Aligned to %#lx\n",size>>i);
 23         }
 24         else
 25             printf("Not Aligned to %#lx\n",size>>i);
 26     return 0;
 27 }
```

output (incorrect)

```
    [sourav@himanshu] ./chkalign 0x924000000 
0Aligned to 0 
Aligned to 0x80000000 
Aligned to 0x40000000 
Aligned to 0x20000000
Aligned to 0x10000000
Aligned to 0x8000000
Aligned to 0x4000000
```

as we can see the value of addr when printed after atoi function shows 0.

kindly advise...

Comment: did you try `strtol()` instead?

Comment: Don't include line numbers or we can't easily copy/paste your code into a text editor and compile it.

Comment: And really cook your code down to a minimal example when asking here. Your problem has nothing to do with interpreting addresses or so. As you have correctly in your title, you have a problem with `atoi`, so work that problem, and omit all the uninteresting stuff.

Comment: Please don't use line numbers in code samples, it complicates CPR (cut paste and run) and PCV (posting corrected version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify a platform, be aware that memory addresses are not necessarily the same size as `int`.  `atoi` returns an `int`, hence the problem.

Even `long` may not be large enough to hold a memory address (as in Windows IIRC).  Therefore you should use `strtoull` returning an `unsigned long long` guaranteed to be at least 64 bits. Also use `0` as the base for conversion, allowing addresses to be entered as `0x80000000` on the command line.  Also be more consistent and portable with your types: `long` is not necessarily 64 bits, so it should not be printed as `"%lx"` in `printf`.

Also work on your style.  Consistency helps avoid bugs.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int aligned(uint64_t addr, uint64_t pgsize) {
    return (addr % pgsize) == 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    uint64_t addr, size;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: ./chkalign <address>\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    addr = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    printf("Address %#llx:\n", (unsigned long long)addr);
    //addr = 0x1900000000;
    size = 0x100000000;

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (aligned(addr, size >> i)) {
            printf("Aligned to %#llx\n", (unsigned long long)size >> i);
        } else {
            printf("Not Aligned to %#llx\n", (unsigned long long)size >> i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The number `0x924000000` is in hex so you should use `strtol()` and store it in `long`

```
addr=strtol(argv[1], NULL, 16);
```

Comment: `strtoul` makes more sense in this case.

Comment: And using `0` instead of `16` would allow to read in numbers in a more general format, decimal, octal or hexadecimal.

Comment: when using the strtoull **addr=strtoull(argv[1],NULL,0);** on printing the address it prints incorrectly
 **./chkalign 0x924000000**
**addr:0x24000000** instead of _0x924000000_

Comment: It depends on the size of `long` on your platform.  It is only 32 bits in Windows.  Check my answer.